# Java newInstance of Generic Class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am working with Java Generic classes (in this example, these are the Collection classes), and Reflection. I would like to be able to use reflection to take in a Class, check if it is an instance of a List, and then invoke the add method to it.

However, I've faced some difficulties in trying to put as the parameters to invoke the method call, and getting the declared method (shown where I put-what???). Both of those method parameter calls, require an object of type  `Class<?>` which is the parameter type of needed for the `add` methods being invoked, which I don't know, since `T` itself is a generic.

Any help is appreciated! I apologize if the question is unclear, I tried the best I could to clarify.

```
static <T> void TestACollection(Class<T> clazz) {
     T element=clazz.newInstance();
     if(element instanceof List<?>)
     Method m=clazz.getDeclaredMethod("add", what???  ); 
     m.invoke(element, what???);
}
```

Comment: First `what???` is `Object`. Second `what???` is whatever you are adding.

Comment: Due to type erasure, this isn't very possible.  (it depends how you got that `Class<T>`)

Comment: Btw `m` is undefined, when you try to call `invoke`.

Comment: So @Dima, if I passed in a `List.class` , calling      `clazz.getDeclaredMethod("add", Object.class)`  would work?   And for the second part, if I added a String object, would `T element` be an instance of `List<String>` ?

Comment: `element` is an instance of `List`. There are no generics in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what you are trying to do is this:

```
public static <T> List<T> makeList() {
   List<T> list = (List<T>) new ArrayList();
   return list;
}

//...
{
   List<String> list = makeList();
   list.add( "Howdy" );
}
```

Which works as-is in Java 8.  In earlier versions you may have to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to the assignment.

Comment: The argument `type` is unused and unnecessary. What you have is just a really verbose way of doing
`public static <T> List<T> makeList() {
  return new ArrayList<T>();
}`

Comment: Oh yeah.  I copied the OP's method spec and ended up not needing the type parameter, which I didn't notice.   Good catch.